# ServerAlias not working - ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I got the following `.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I am also using Let's Encrypt SSL. All requests to `example.com` work just fine and are redirected to HTTPS. The problem is that the alias domain doesn't work. When I request `www.example.com` I get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS error. Do you have the appropriate `A` or `CNAME` (assuming this is the same domain) configured pointing to your server?

Comment: @MrWhite seems like I forgot that part, I just added A record for www in my AWS control panel, still not wrking but I guess it will take some time to update?

Comment: Is it working now? Adding a _new_ DNS record shouldn't take long to be read. But you can test this locally immediately by overriding your local DNS.

Comment: @MrWhite adding a new record for www worked, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've converted my comment to an answer - as this could help other readers. If you can accept it, that would be great thanks. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS resolution error and suggests the request is not even reaching your server.

In addition to the config presented in your question, you would also need the appropriate `A` record (or `CNAME` record if these are the same domain, with just a difference in subdomain) defined in the DNS that points `www.example.com` to your server. Without this, the request cannot be *resolved*.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

Your redirection block is overly complex. You don't need mod_rewrite, a single mod_alias `Redirect` is all that's required. Assuming you also want to canonicalise the hostname? You don't need to check the `SERVER_NAME` because presumably you want to redirect whatever request reached the port 80 vHost?

For example, the following would probably suffice:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```